# Dual Boot Win 7 and Ubuntu and can not get wired connection to work

Tags: networking, dual-boot

Recently I decided to try out Linux and chose Ubuntu. After backing up all my files I went ahead and installed Ubuntu 15.04. I did this in a partition as a dual boot knowing my family would still want access to Windows at least for a little time.

When I boot up into Windows I can connect no problem to the internet. My problem is when I boot into Ubuntu I can not.

I can and will run any reports that would help me solve this, I would just need walked through as I am completely new to Linux and the CLI. Willing to learn though.

I have tried to search for a solution but nothing seems to match my issue or the solution that work for them did not work.

Is there an easy fix that I am missing? When I go into the router setting with my other PC (A work laptop) connected (wired) I see the laptop connected but not the desktop.

I also tried the LTS Ubuntu and Linux Mint with same results which makes think it is something Windows is doing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I went ahead and installed Ubuntu on Virtual Box from Windows and was able to connect to the internet. Still not sure why I will not connect when I boot into Ubuntu. I also remember that during install at one point it showed that it did not detect an internet connection. So this was an issue from the start. I am going to try to remove Ubuntu and reinstall it and see if that helps.